# Symlink some file of a tree to another folder and conserve folder structure

Tags: command-line, symlink, cp

Assuming this tree (top-X & tX-sub-X are folders, and all sub-folder containing a .csv and various other file extensions.)

```
Base
├── top-1
│   ├── t1_sub-1 
│   ├── t1_sub-2 
│   └── t1_sub-3 
│
└── top-2
    ├── t2_sub-1
    ├── t2_sub-2
    └── t2_sub-3
```

and all sub-folder containing a .csv and various other file extensions.

can I symlink all .csv in base to another tree amd have this:

```
Symlinked_base
├── top-1 #directories aren't symlink
│   ├── t1_sub-1 #contains only .csv symlink
│   ├── t1_sub-2 
│   └── t1_sub-3 
│
└── top-2
    ├── t2_sub-1
    ├── t2_sub-2
    └── t2_sub-3
```

I can't test it now but would:

```
sudo find . -name "*.csv" -exec cp -Rs '{}' /path/to/Symlinked_base/
```

if -R is unsupported, would the following work? :

```
 sudo find . -name "*.csv" -exec cp -parents -s '{}' /path/to/Symlinked_base/
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is `t1_sub-1` in `Base` and `Symlinked_base` ? Is that a directory or a file?

Comment: @val0x00ff t1-subs & base are folders will add details

Answer (score 1):

Stow is a package to maintain symlink trees. You can use the --no-folding option to create directories at the destination instead of linking the directories themselves - that should get you what you want.

https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/manual/stow.html